# Trying to set up the GNU C++ COMPILER, but I get an error I don't understand when I try to compile hello.cpp

Tags: c++, mingw, gnu

So I bought this book called [C++ Programming In Easy Steps by Mike McGrath](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1840784326) online.

In the instructions it specifies to create a source file written in C++, the infamous "helo world". So I created my cpp file through sublime text editor and moved it to a file called MyPrograms in my C directory. 
The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{
cout << "hello world"<< endl ; 
return 0 ;
}
```

I have also tried:
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
cout << "hello world"<< endl ; 
return 0 ;
}
```

Ok so I saved this file as hello.cpp in C:\MyPrograms.
Then here is where the error occurs....
I open cmd. 
I do "c++"
I receive the message "c++: no input files".Which is what I'm supposed to recieve according to the book. 
I proceed to do "cd\myprograms" to enter into the MyPrograms directory.
Once in that directory I do "c++ hello.cpp". According to the book this is supposed to compile my source file and create an executable file next to it. Instead I get a long error message that end in collect 2: 1d returned 1 exit status.

When I visit MyPrograms no executable file has been made next to the original cpp file. 
I have also tried to do "c++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe" but it gives me the error again. All of this is done on the command prompt. [image: The command prompt error]

Please help :(

Comment: GNU compiler for C++ named g++. I don't know where you found "c++". However you should to add "g++" to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like MinGW isn't installed properly.

First, it looks like you are trying to use version 4.0.3 but it may be conflicting with a version 3.4.5 that you installed previously (one in c:\mingw and the other in e:\p\giaw\src\pkg).

The latest version of MinGW is 4.7.2.1 which you can install from here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW

But it looks like you're just starting out and it may be better to work with something that's better optimized for Windows (unless you're trying to compile Free Software). You can get a copy of Visual Studio Express for free here:

http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop

There are older versions available as well if you scroll down (VSE 2010).

Comment: I did have visual studio but I am really trying to start out with this so that I can follow the book better... Also I tried looking for the GNU compiler in the control panel and couldn't find it, and I'm afraid if I remove the installations on the setup file it will mess with my system's dll's

Comment: I wouldn't really worry about that. Search your filesystem for MinGW and you should see that's it's pretty self-contained. Also note that I didn't suggest deleting anything from your system folders. If you see that you have multiple installations, either remove (or rename) the old one out of the way, or remove them both and get the latest version.

Comment: So it would be completely okay for me to go to C:- MinGW and completely delete the folder? I would like to try to re-install everything.

Comment: If you're at all concerned, just rename it. If it works after a reinstall, then you can remove the old copy. Of course, it's already not working, so ...